# PHP : Preventing multiple javascript inclusions

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, include

Hi i'm having a problem with inclusion of javascripts specifically Google maps API.

I have a page for example that includes the library:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=places,visualization"></script>

//some page contents

$this->widget('MyWidgetThatIncludesGoogleAPI',array(
..
));
```

The problem arises when I call my widget which also includes google maps api, and even if I don't initially include the maps api in this page. Calling the widget twice does the same.

I get an error saying that Google Maps API has been loaded multiple times, is there a programmatic way to handle duplicate inclusion of js?

Comment: don't want to include it twice? then don't include it twice

Comment: as i've mentioned in my post; even if i don't include it, calling a widget twice, or even doing a renderPartial() to a page having it causes the inclusion fo the js twice.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a global variable to track whether it has already been included. You could then create a function to include the script if it hasn't already been included.

```
$includedGoogleMaps = false;
function includeGoogleMaps() {
    global $includedGoogleMaps;
    if (!includedGoogleMaps) {
        echo '<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=places,visualization"></script>';
        $includeGoogleMaps = true;
    }
}
```

The function isn't exactly necessary but it makes everything a lot cleaner.